# A class within a public class and creating a new object access to different variables

Tags: java

I've failed to find how to get a class within a public class. There is no syntax errors. The error comes from the receiving the methods for the class.

I am using Dr. Java to run this. I've tried to make a separate file attachments suggested in other user solutions, but the version I have does not have the tools in the other user versions. Please let me know how to achieve this.

```
public class TestLab2Bronze {
  public void main(String[] args) {
    //Create the teams in the Central division of the NHL.
    //This is intentionally very simple brute-force code.
    HockeyTeam team1 = new HockeyTeam("Winnipeg",22,14,8,"=",0);
    HockeyTeam team2 = new HockeyTeam("Chicago",28,13,2,"=",0);
    HockeyTeam team3 = new HockeyTeam("Colorado",18,17,8,"=",0);
    HockeyTeam team4 = new HockeyTeam("St. Louis",27,13,3,"=",0);
    HockeyTeam team5 = new HockeyTeam("Dallas",19,16,7,"=",0);
    HockeyTeam team6 = new HockeyTeam("Minnesota",18,19,5,"=",0);
    HockeyTeam team7 = new HockeyTeam("Nashville",29,9,4,"=",0);

    //Print out all 7 objects, again with simple code.
    System.out.println("Initial teams:\n" +
              team1 + "\n" + team2 + "\n" + team3 + "\n" + team4 + "\n" +
              team5 + "\n" + team6 + "\n" + team7 + "\n");

    //Record the results of some fictional games
    team1.won(); team2.lost();          //Winnipeg beat Chicago
    team1.won(); team3.lostOvertime();  //Winnipeg beat Colorado
    team1.won(); team4.lostOvertime();  //Winnipeg beat St. Louis
    team1.won(); team5.lost();          //Winnipeg beat Dallas
    team1.won(); team6.lost();          //Winnipeg beat Minnesota
    team1.won(); team7.lostOvertime();  //Winnipeg beat Nashville
    //OK. So the Jets are really hot right now.
    team4.won(); team2.lost();          //St. Louis beat Chicago
    team3.won(); team5.lost();          //Colorado beat Dallas   

    //Print out the 7 objects again, to see the changes.
    System.out.println("Final teams:\n" +
              team1 + "\n" + team2 + "\n" + team3 + "\n" + team4 + "\n" +
              team5 + "\n" + team6 + "\n" + team7 + "\n");
  }
}

class HockeyTeam {
  public int point;

  public HockeyTeam(String city, int scoreone, int scoretwo, int scorethree, String equals, int point) {
    this.point = point;
  }

  public void won() {
    point += 2;
  }

  public void lost() {
    point += 0;
  }

  public void lostOvertime() {
    point += 1;
  }

  public int points() {
    return point;
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the the second class INSIDE the first class.

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of class. If you are using 8n same pkg there is no issue. It will issue if there is different path of classess. At that time you need to set classpath od calling class. Kindly swt the class path of the file and then you can use it with current class

Comment: Yes I've changed the Hockey class location and set it to static and it runs find, except it does not print out the values (readable). Initial teams: TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@143b388 Final teams: TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@67dd9e I would like to print: Initial teams: Winnipeg(22,14,8=52) Final teams: Winnipeg(28,14,8=64) Thank you for your suggestions and solutions

Answer (score 0):

main method must be static:

> public static void main(String[] args)

HockeyTeam should be in Test5Lab2Bronze class, static and be declared as following:

> public static class HockeyTeam

code should look like this:

```
public class TestLab2Bronze {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the teams in the Central division of the NHL.
        // This is intentionally very simple brute-force code.
        HockeyTeam team1 = new HockeyTeam("Winnipeg", 22, 14, 8, "=", 0);
        HockeyTeam team2 = new HockeyTeam("Chicago", 28, 13, 2, "=", 0);
        HockeyTeam team3 = new HockeyTeam("Colorado", 18, 17, 8, "=", 0);
        HockeyTeam team4 = new HockeyTeam("St. Louis", 27, 13, 3, "=", 0);
        HockeyTeam team5 = new HockeyTeam("Dallas", 19, 16, 7, "=", 0);
        HockeyTeam team6 = new HockeyTeam("Minnesota", 18, 19, 5, "=", 0);
        HockeyTeam team7 = new HockeyTeam("Nashville", 29, 9, 4, "=", 0);

        // Print out all 7 objects, again with simple code.
        System.out.println("Initial teams:\n" + team1 + "\n" + team2 + "\n"
                + team3 + "\n" + team4 + "\n" + team5 + "\n" + team6 + "\n"
                + team7 + "\n");

        // Record the results of some fictional games
        team1.won();
        team2.lost(); // Winnipeg beat Chicago
        team1.won();
        team3.lostOvertime(); // Winnipeg beat Colorado
        team1.won();
        team4.lostOvertime(); // Winnipeg beat St. Louis
        team1.won();
        team5.lost(); // Winnipeg beat Dallas
        team1.won();
        team6.lost(); // Winnipeg beat Minnesota
        team1.won();
        team7.lostOvertime(); // Winnipeg beat Nashville
        // OK. So the Jets are really hot right now.
        team4.won();
        team2.lost(); // St. Louis beat Chicago
        team3.won();
        team5.lost(); // Colorado beat Dallas

        // Print out the 7 objects again, to see the changes.
        System.out.println("Final teams:\n" + team1 + "\n" + team2 + "\n"
                + team3 + "\n" + team4 + "\n" + team5 + "\n" + team6 + "\n"
                + team7 + "\n");

    }// main

    public static class HockeyTeam {
        public int point;

        public HockeyTeam(String city, int scoreone, int scoretwo,
                int scorethree, String equals, int point)

        {
            this.point = point;

        }

        public void won()

        {
            point += 2;

        }

        public void lost()

        {
            point += 0;

        }

        public void lostOvertime()

        {
            point += 1;

        }

        public int points()

        {
            return point;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I've changed the Hockey class location and set it to static and it runs find, except it does not print out the values (readable).
Initial teams: TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@143b388

Final teams: TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@67dd9e 
I would like to print:

Initial teams: Winnipeg(22,14,8=52) 

Final teams: Winnipeg(28,14,8=64) 
Thank you for your suggestions and solutions

Comment: the way you are printing the teams objects, you are actually calling the method toString implemented at Object class. What you have to do is override the toString method, to it prints what you wish.
Later I will edit my solution so you can see what a meant.
Btw please upvote my aswer so i get more then 50 of rep, so i can comment on answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've changed the Hockey class location and set it to static and it runs find, except it does not print out the values in text language form (readable).

Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\Users\Acer

> run TestLab2Bronze
>   Initial teams:
>   TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@67dd9e
>   TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@143b388
>   TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@1f2e781
>   TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@14b9a40
>   TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@1842d5a
>   TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@1bd1811
>   TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@1ed3c88

Final teams:
TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@67dd9e
TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@143b388
TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@1f2e781
TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@14b9a40
TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@1842d5a
TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@1bd1811
TestLab2Bronze$HockeyTeam@1ed3c88

I would like to print:

Initial teams: Winnipeg(22,14,8=52) Chicago(28,13,2=58) Colorado(18,17,8=44) St. Louis(27,13,3=57) Dallas(19,16,7=45) Minnesota(18,19,5=41) Nashville(29,9,4=62)

Final teams: Winnipeg(28,14,8=64) Chicago(28,15,2=58) Colorado(19,17,9=47) St. Louis(28,13,4=60) Dallas(19,18,7=45) Minnesota(18,20,5=41) Nashville(29,9,5=63)`

Same spacing as the original just the text to be readable. Thank you for your suggestions and solutions

Comment: Class `HockeyTeam` needs a proper `toString` Method, else you get that ugly result from the implementation in `Object` (containing the class name and the identity hash).